# Laravel 5 middleware executes even after restriction

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-middleware

I have a middleware which restrict access to route if the route is not allowed to him. I added it in:`kernel.php`

```
 protected $middleware = [ \App\Http\Middleware\MyMiddlware::class,]


 public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $response = $next($request);
    $currentRoute = $request->route()->getName();
    $accessibleMenu = $this->menu->where('route_name', $currentRoute)->first();

  dd('middleware');

    if ($this->auth->check() && !is_null($accessibleMenu)) {

        $userRole = $request->user()->role()->first()->id;


        if (!is_null($userRole ) && $userRole ==1) {

            return $response;
        }
    }

    return Response::make(view('noPermission'), 404);
}
```

Route:

```
   Route::get('menu/list','MenuController@index')->name('menu-list');
```

controller function::

```
    public function index($parent_id = null)
{
     dd('executed');
    $menus = $this->menu->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate(5000);

    return view('menu.index', compact('menus'));
}
```

Now for real: if role id is 2, the middleware should return 404 view without executing the route.  But it prints executed string on screen!

1.If i deleted or comment:

```
 $response = $next($request);
```

it returns

```
Call to a member function getName() on null
```

2. If i move route registration to

   'web' => [
               \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
               \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
               \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
               // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
               \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
               \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
               \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
               \App\Http\Middleware\Activity::class,
               \App\Http\Middleware\MyMiddlware::class,
           ],

and comment:

```
 $response = $next($request);
```

then screen prints "middleware" and the middleware works

My question is why the middlware allow the function execution if i use this

```
 $response = $next($request);
```

in the first of the handle function?
Why the middlware does not work and returns null for `getName()` if i use in `protected $middleware = []` array ?

laravel says in kernel.php for - protected $middleware = []:
* These middleware are run during every request to your application.

why is this allow even after i restrict access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had difficulty reading thru this, however I *think* you want to change 2 lines:

remove `$response = $next($request);`

change `return $response;` to `return $next($request);`

I think you want to change these lines because `$next($request)` is the full execution.

Comment: yes. but why is not  the middleware working when get the closure method in a variable :$response?

Comment: Why global middleware allow controller function without restriction if i use $response = $next($request);?

Comment: $next($request) will execute whatever is next and put the result into the variable.  The variable is not a closure.

Comment: In other words, you're middleware is actually processing after.  Which can be fine in some situations.  It's called afterMiddleware.

Comment: Go to this page and search for "before & after" https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/middleware  it's just bellow the first screen, but has no anchor tag.